# Can I use an anchor tag in alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script> 
 CheckFedderalTimeStatus(){
alert('Federal law restricts sending of mobile text messages between 9PM and 8AM of recipient`s local time. If you believe that the nature of your message does not fall under this restriction (e.g. emergency alert), please <a href="#inline1" class="fancybox" style="color:#1B91DA; text-decoration:none;">click here</a>to apply for an exception.'); 
}</script>
<a href="#" onclick="CheckFedderalTimeStatus()">Click ME </a>
```

can i use anchor tag in alert box

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: no you can't. HTML inside of an alert will be shown as pure text.

```
alert("This is a test: <a href='#'>is this a link?</a>. No it's not.");
```

Results in:

```
>  This is a test: <a href='#'>is this a link?</a>. No it's not.
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/ao5od4gy/

You can use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) as an alternative.

Comment: can i use anchor tag in jQuery ui dialog

Comment: I think using JQuery UI for a simple task like this is overkill.. Perhaps attempt making your own -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RLE2Q7OzME

Comment: As far as I know you can use valid HTML in jQuery Dialog, yes!

Comment: As @PatrickGeyer said you could for sure always create your own "alert box", which would avoid implementing jQuery UI.